# How to achieve SlidingExpiration with Cookieless Authentication? Is it possible

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to achieve sliding expiration using cookieless authentication in asp.net. Here is my web.config authentication section:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
          protection="All"
           timeout="2880"
           name=".USERLOGINCONTROLAUTH"
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="login.aspx"
           cookieless="false"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
  </authentication>
```

I've tried setting slidingExpiration attribute to true but no luck. Later I also went through MSDN documentation and it says it extends the timeout of valid cookies. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the only valid settings for the cookieless attribute are UseUri, UseCookies, AutoDetect and UseDeviceProfile. Additionally I found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2006/11/11/don-t-slide-your-expiration-without-cookies.aspx) that suggests that you should not slide your expiration without cookies.

> The problem is that with cookieless forms authentication, the ticket
>   is actually part of the Url.  When the timeout is updated in the
>   ticket, that means the serialized text representation of the ticket
>   also changes.  As a result we need to change the Url itself to reflect
>   the new value.  Unlike cookies, you can’t rewrite a Url on the server
>   and have the client transparently pick up the new Url.  Instead you
>   have to force a redirect because the redirect forces the browser to
>   reload the document and update the Url that you see in the address
>   bar.